# Asymptotic Relation as Boundary Condition

Tags: differential-equations, asymptotics

I want to solve a system of non-linear second order differential equations. For some of the unknown functions there are boundary conditions that i know how to write them in Mathematica. One of the unknows satisfies the following asymptotic expression:

$$b(r \rightarrow \infty) \sim \frac{r^2}{l^2} $$

My question is if is there a way to use an asymptotic relation as a boundary condition in Mathematica.

Comment: I presume that you wish to solve your system of non-linear second order differential equations numerically.  If so, you must provide a boundary condition at some large value of `r`, because you cannot integrate to infinity.  Then, the boundary condition is `b[rmax] == rmax^2 / l^2`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but no. I am seeking an exact solution. The equations are in this post:https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/571649/derivation-of-mtz-black-hole

Comment: Frankly, I do not think that `DSolve` can handle these equations, but you can give it a try.  I suggest you start with no boundary conditions, and see what DSolve gives.  If it returns an answer, then applying the boundary conditions at that point should be straightforward.